How to prevent a content carousel from appearing on top of a navbar when the menu is open in ReactJS?
I have a ReactJS project where I have a navbar with a mobile dropdown menu and a content carousel on the homepage. When the menu is open on mobile, the carousel appears on top of the menu, which I want to prevent.
Here’s a simplified version of my setup:

Navbar – The mobile menu is controlled by a useState hook and toggles the visibility of the dropdown.

Carousel – The carousel slides through content every few seconds and is displayed below the navbar.


I’ve tried adding z-index to both the navbar and carousel, but the carousel still ends up on top of the menu when it's opened. I also ensured the navbar has a position: relative, but I am not sure why the carousel isn't staying below the menu.
Homepage
    return (
        <div className='mt-3 grid grid-cols-2 relative '>
            {/* carousel */}
            <div className='overflow-hidden z-0'>
                <div
                    className='flex transition-transform duration-700 ease-in-out'
                    style={{
                        transform: `translateX(-${currentIndex * 100}%)`,
                    }}
                >
                    {artists.map(artist => (
                        <div key={artist.artistId} className='w-full flex-shrink-0 p-4 bg-slate-700'>
                            <img
                                src={artist.recentArtwork?.images?.frontView}
                                alt={artist.recentArtwork?.title || 'Artwork'}
                                className='w-full h-52 object-cover'
                            />
                            <div className='p-4 text-center'>
                                <img
                                    src={artist.avatar}
                                    alt={artist.fullName}
                                    className='w-16 h-16 rounded-xl mx-auto mb-3 border-2 border-indigo-500'
                                />
                                <h2 className='text-xl font-semibold'>{artist.fullName}</h2>
                                <p className='text-gray-500 text-sm'>{artist.email}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div></div>
        </div>
    );

Navbar
    return (
        <nav
            className='bg-gray-100 font-custom dark:bg-gray-800 text-gray-800 dark:text-white lg:px-5 px-2 border-b border-gray-300 dark:border-gray-700 drop-shadow'
            ref={menuRef}
        >
            <div className='flex gap-x-3 sm:gap-x-5 sm:px-3 xl:gap-x-20 py-2 px-2 relative'>
                <div className='shrink-0 flex'>
                    <Link
                        to='/home'
                        onClick={handleLinkClick}
                        className='flex items-center font-extrabold font-ranchers text-xl '
                    >
                        <div className='flex gap-1'>
                            <div className=''>
                                <img src={smallIcon} alt='logo' className='h-auto w-6 sm:w-7' />
                            </div>
                            <div className='hidden leading-[1.1rem] sm:flex flex-col justify-center'>
                                <p className='text-cyan-600'>ETHEREAL</p>
                                <p>CANVAS</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Link>
                </div>

                <div className='relative flex items-center w-full'>
                    <span className='absolute inset-y-0 right-51 flex items-center pl-3'>
                        <CiSearch className='h-5 w-5 text-gray-500' />
                    </span>
                    <input
                        type='text'
                        className='w-full pl-10 pr-4 py-1 border text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md'
                        placeholder='Search...'
                    />
                </div>

                <div className='lg:flex items-center lg:gap-4 xl:gap-10 hidden'>
                    {['Home', 'Artists', 'Artworks', 'Marketplace', 'About'].map(link => (
                        <Link
                            key={link}
                            to={`/${link.toLowerCase()}`}
                            className='text-sm font-custom font-extrabold text-slate-700 hover:text-blue-500 dark:hover:text-blue-400'
                            onClick={handleLinkClick}
                        >
                            {link}
                        </Link>
                    ))}
                </div>

                {/* Avatar and Dark Mode */}
                <div className='shrink-0 flex items-center'>
                    {isLoggedIn && (role === 'artist' || role === 'collector') ? (
                        <div className='hidden lg:flex items-center gap-5'>
                            <Dropdown
                                label={fullName}
                                options={options}
                                logout={handleLogout}
                                avatar={<Avatar src={avatar} name={name || fullName} alt='User Avatar' />}
                                role={role}
                            />
                            <button
                                onClick={toggleDarkMode}
                                className='hidden lg:flex text-xl'
                                aria-label='Toggle Dark Mode'
                            >
                                {isDarkMode ? <TbSunFilled /> : <TbMoonFilled />}
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    ) : (
                        <div className='flex gap-4'>
                            <Link
                                to='/login'
                                onClick={handleLinkClick}
                                className='hidden lg:block px-3 py-1 rounded-lg text-xs bg-blue-500 text-white 
                            transition ease-in-out delay-150 hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-110 
                            hover:bg-indigo-500 duration-300'
                            >
                                Login / Register
                            </Link>

                            <button
                                onClick={toggleDarkMode}
                                className='hidden lg:flex text-xl'
                                aria-label='Toggle Dark Mode'
                            >
                                {isDarkMode ? <TbSunFilled /> : <TbMoonFilled />}
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    )}

                    <button className='lg:hidden text-xl' onClick={() => setIsMenuOpen(!isMenuOpen)}>
                        {isMenuOpen ? <CgCloseR /> : <TbMenu2 />}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            {/* DROPDOWN */}
            <div
                className={`${isMenuOpen ? 'block' : 'hidden'} lg:hidden absolute bg-gray-100 w-full left-0 right-0`}
            >
                {['Home', 'Artists', 'Artworks', 'Marketplace', 'About'].map(link => (
                    <div
                        key={link}
                        className='hover:bg-zinc-200 hover:border-l-4 hover:border-l-orange-400 hover:rounded hover:ml-1 text-sm'
                    >
                        <Link
                            to={`/${link.toLowerCase()}`}
                            className='block py-2 pl-3 font-custom font-medium'
                            onClick={handleLinkClick}
                        >
                            {link}
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                ))}

                {isLoggedIn ? (
                    <div className='border-t grid grid-cols-3 font-custom px-3 py-5'>
                        <div className='flex items-center col-span-2'>
                            <Avatar src={avatar} name={fullName} alt='User Avatar' />
                            <div className='pl-1'>
                                <p className='text-xs text-slate-800'>{fullName}</p>
                                <p className='text-[10px] text-slate-500'>{email}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className='flex items-center justify-end col-span-1'>
                            <button
                                onClick={() => {
                                    handleLogout();
                                    handleLinkClick();
                                }}
                                className='text-xs px-3 py-1 rounded-md text-white bg-red-600'
                            >
                                Logout
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ) : (
                    <div className='border-t flex items-center justify-between px-3 py-5'>
                        <Link
                            to='/login'
                            onClick={handleLinkClick}
                            className='px-3 py-1 rounded-lg text-xs bg-blue-500 text-white 
                            transition ease-in-out delay-150 hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-110 
                            hover:bg-indigo-500 duration-300'
                        >
                            Login / Register
                        </Link>
                        <button
                            onClick={toggleDarkMode}
                            className='flex text-2xl'
                            aria-label='Toggle Dark Mode'
                        >
                            {isDarkMode ? <TbSunFilled /> : <TbMoonFilled />}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        </nav>
    );

